# Print a 3D object animation in 2D

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

Here what I need to do is print the 3D animation transitions in my animation clip in 2D format. For example printing a human animation walking on paper. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You should tell more about what you already have. I would assume, you have a 3D animation of a 3D model (walking character) and you want to "print" that in 2D, somehow like a storyboard. Is that it? Do you need this runtime or is it a dev process that could be done in photoshop or blender?

Comment: @fafase Yes, you have guessed it right. I need to print it like a storyboard and also it is to be done at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several aspects to consider:

1. Splitting the animation up into frames
2. Rendering the frame
3. Retrieving the rendered frame

#### Splitting the animation up into frames

Before you render a frame, you have to decide, which frame it should be. Depending on your requirements you may want to render only keyframes (frames that have been defined by the animation artist or the mocap data, but may not be evenly distributed over the duration of the animation), or to render frames that are evenly distributed over the duration of the animation (i.e. render one frame every 0.2 seconds).
Once you know the frame, you can tell the AnimationController to jump to that specific frame and update the 3D model accordingly.

#### Rendering the frame

Again, depending on your requirements, you may want to consider using a Camera with an orthographic projection. This will remove any perspective distortions, making it easier to visually analyze the animation. If of course the goal is a more visually appealing or "artistic" presentation, a perspective projection may be desired as well.

#### Retrieving the frame

As you want to print out the rendering, you need to retrieve the result of the rendering. You can do this either by letting Unity take a screenshot (Application.CaptureScreenshot), or by having a RenderTexture and setting this as the render target of your Camera. You can then copy the contents of the RenderTexture to a Texture2D (Texture2D.ReadPixels()) and save that to disk (Texture2D.EncodeToPNG/JPG())